# does a machine need to be in the same domain to connect to an AD server

Tags: active-directory, connection, domain-name

I'm newbie to AD,
 I'm trying to join an AD server, using an App and an LDAP client (Apache Directory studio) but I can't, I remarked that, from my server I can ping the AD domain, but from my local machine I can't.
so my question is does a machine  need to be in the same domain as the server to connect to it ?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "connect to an AD's LDAP service" if you say "join an AD server" (joining an AD domain is something very different): No,you just need to be allowed to connect to the server, which can (and often is) prevented by firewall rules and the like for everything outside the AD network.

Comment: I don't know what is the difference between "connect" and "join", what I want is that a user that use my application deployed in an app server running in a machine 'A' could be authenticated based on it's credential existed in AD (the machine 'A' in the AD server are have different domain)